# Как сделать так чтобы объект View не сжимался у правого и нижнего края RelativeLayout

Tags: android, view

Как сделать так чтобы объекты View не сжимались у правого и нижнего края `RelativeLayout`, а сохраняли бы прежний размер просто выходя за пределы экрана.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разметку скинь посмотреть бы

Answer (score 1):

У вас `RelativeLayout`, скорее всего, имеет размеры `match_parent`, что означает, что его размер строго по экрану. Так как `RelativeLayout` - это `ViewGroup`, которая рассчитывает положение и размер `view` добавленных в нее, она не может расположить `view` за пределами себя. У вас есть выбор либо использовать фиксированый `ScrollView`, и с ним что-то пробовать, либо сделать размеры `RelativeLayout` больше размера экрана.